# is it posible, create a temp #table inside a openrowset?

Tags: sql, openrowset, temp-tables

i am trying execute this query but i got a error:

```
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid object name '#test1'.
```

my code:

```
select * from openrowset ('SQLOLEDB','DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.12.131.58;UID=sa;PWD=desarrollo','



create table #test1
(
id int,
name1 varchar(50)
)

insert into #test1
select cliente,nomcli from opepte.dbo.clientes

select * from #test1

/*this is a example but in real query i need manipulate this information and return 
a resulset with few rows
*/


')
```

but this other query works fine.

```
select * from openrowset ('SQLOLEDB','DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.12.131.58;UID=sa;PWD=desarrollo','



create table #test1
(
id int,
name1 varchar(50)
)

--insert into #test1
select cliente,nomcli from opepte.dbo.clientes

--select * from #test1

/*this is a example but in real query i need manipulate this information and return 
a resulset with few rows
*/


')
```

Note: insert into #test1 and select * from #test1 are coment

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do, that you're trying to create a temp table?  Could you just use a Common Table Expression (CTE) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use FMTONLY & NOCOUNT
2. Just why not to use tabled-variable instead of temp? Since you are explicitly returns data via this code, nobody will use your temp table again.
3. Also consider more robust and secure provider and connection string: 'SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=yes;'

   ```
   select * from openrowset ('SQLOLEDB','DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.12.131.58;UID=sa;PWD=desarrollo', N'

   SET FMTONLY OFF
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   declare @q int = 1

   declare @test1 table
   (
   id int,
   name1 varchar(50)
   )

   insert into @test1
   select 1,''q''

   insert into @test1
   select 1,''q''

   select * from @test1

   /*this is a example but in real query i need manipulate this information and return 
   a resulset with few rows
   */
   ')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can as the openquery/rowset interface is quite limited. Given that the remote server is a SQL server you may be able to use a table based function to delivery the functionality you require. Otherwise you could use a remote execution stored procedure or a linked server to do this.